# SQL Server 2014 - User defined data type - add not null column

Tags: sql-server, user-defined-data-types

I have created a not nullable user defined data type using the below script

```
CREATE TYPE [dbo].[booleano]
FROM TINYINT NOT NULL;
EXECUTE sp_bindefault @defname = N'[dbo].[cero]', @objname = N'[dbo].[booleano]';
```

It has an bind default value, which is 0. 
When I try to add a new column to a table, and this is a not null column it return the following error

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[con_impresion]
ADD [cim_imprime_monto_letras_boo] [dbo].[booleano] NOT NULL;

Rows were detected. The schema update is terminating because data loss might occur.
```

But if add a default constraint to the new column it returns the following error

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[con_impresion]
ADD [cim_imprime_monto_letras_boo] [dbo].[booleano] DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL;

Column already has a DEFAULT bound to it.
```

Comment: While executing your code, I am getting:`The default 'cero' does not exist.` plz provide us with the missing code.

Comment: Seems a bit off to create a type named booleano that is a tinyint. How is 3 a valid boolean? Or 148? Wouldn't a bit datatype make more sense?

Comment: 'cero' is just a defined default

    CREATE DEFAULT [dbo].[cero]
    AS 0.0;

Comment: Sean Lange it also has a Rule that just admit 0 or 1

Comment: @JosueAK, `CREATE DEFAULT` and `sp_bindefault` have been deprecated for several years. I suggest you add the column with the UDT with a DEFAULT constraint.